# Why duplicate HostOnly JS Cookies aren't being removed by host?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to clean-up some duplicate cookies. The issue was initially, these cookies were only scoped for the current sub-domain that set them. We changed the scope of these cookies to be globally scoped for the domain. This left us with duplicate cookies with different domains scoped. I wanted to remove these domain scoped cookies but the code doesn't work unless the "hostonly" flag is manually deactivated? I thought that if the same domain that set the cookies, served the code to remove the cookies then I wouldn't have to worry about that "hostOnly" flag? Doesn't appear to be true? Anyone understand why this isn't deleting the cookies and how/if I can?

```
try{
function clearCookie(name, domain, path){
var domain = domain || document.domain;
var path = path || "/";
document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=" + domain + "; path=" + path;
};

clearCookie("visitCount","www.mysite.com","/");
clearCookie("lastVisit","www.mysite.com","/");
clearCookie("visitedPreviously","www.mysite.com","/");
clearCookie("navElemName","www.mysite.com","/");
clearCookie("s_uniqueUserID","www.mysite.com","/");
clearCookie("pcidSet","www.mysite.com","/");

document.cookie = "cookiesCleaned=1; path=/; domain=.mysite.com";
}catch (e) {}
```

Comment: @Bergi - Not sure what you mean by no access from scripting? JS set these cookies and reads them? So there is no way to remove these unwanted cookies?

Comment: @Bergi - sre you talking about "httpOnly" or "hostOnly"? JS set these cookies.

Comment: Oops, you're right, I confused the two.

Comment: I figured it out. The cookies weren't being specified with a domain when being set so I had to remove the domain setting.